# OpenSSL unknown protocol error on aws connection

Tags: ssl, curl, amazon-s3, https

I get:

> Excon::Error::Socket (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3
>   read server hello A: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError))

when trying to upload files to amazon s3 via curl
curl request:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/{:project_id}/upload -F 'files=@file_path.jpg'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Using of carrierwave-aws gem instead fog resolved this problem